# stream reader doesnt update its content until i close an application that that is dynamically changing the text file

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader

```
      using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\darren\Contacts\Desktop\staffs.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    list.Add(line); // Add to list.

                }
                sr.Close();
                fs.Close();

            }
```

Code works fine until i open up the other application thats using this text file. thanks

Comment: Text files make horrible databases.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Is this code block attached to a button action or another event?

Comment: The other application probably has an output buffer and doesn't actually write to the file until it has to.  Closing it forces it to flush its buffer.

Comment: @Plutonix im just using this program to orgainise the text file so its usable by a database

Comment: @BenVoigt yea i think so its a swipe card reader once i close the prompt its works fine.

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa not it runs every 30 seconds to organize the text file and send the results to another

Comment: StreamWriter has an AutoFlush property.  Whatever app you use that writes the file doesn't.  Use your telephone to talk to its author.

Answer (score 0):

You could be dealing with locking issues or it could be related to buffers, you could try using .flush() to see if that helps.  But the initial comment is correct, text files are not reliable for multi-application functionality... you could try something like LiteDb and that may be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

> Code works fine until I open up the other application that's using this text file

The file Share and Access settings only determine how your process is willing to share with others. Other process can and will still demand locks on their open file handles. If another process locks the file, you have to wait until it's released. There is no recourse to you.